# Can't find DocuSign login_information rest API under v2.1

Tags: authentication, docusignapi

We have been using DocuSign's "/restapi/v2/login_information" api for authentication but now we have to replace it with another authentication API which is currently available in v2.1.

Please suggest the new API that can replace login_information.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? are you using legacy auth or OAtuh? you should not need to use login_information call, as it's not ported across data-centers (meaning you can only call it if you already know the specific URL for your customer)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. We have been using it since 2016, now we need to replace it with the latest authentication  API.

Comment: I understand. Can you share your code? to explain why you need this API?

Comment: this.authHeader = "X-DocuSign-Authentication";
this.authHeaderValue = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" + docusign_username + "</Username>
<Password>" + docusign_pwd + "</Password><IntegrationKey>" + docusign_integration_key + "</Integration>
</DocuSignCredentials>";

var httpRequest = new HTTPRequest(docusign_login_url); 
httpRequest.addHeader(this.authHeader, this.authHeaderValue);
var response = httpRequest.get();
var responseBody = new JSONParser().parse(response.getBody());

Comment: yes, so this is using the legacy auth, you will have to change to use OAuth.
do you want to use a code example as a way to start? or would you like to read the document and follow the instructions?

Comment: you need to choose if you use JWT or Auth Code Grant

Comment: Thank you so much Inbar. I appreciate your quick responses. I will read the document and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change form legacy authentication to the modern OAuth.
You can follow https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication and start thinking about using wither Auth Code Grant or JWT.
You can find code examples with the code here:
https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp
This repo has code for both types of Authentication methods.

Answer (score 0):

The replacement for login_information is [userInfo](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/)